# How to prevent UIView passing touch events to UIView's superview?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, events

I have a `UIViewController` object (`bottomViewController`) in the window, and a `UIView` object (upperView) on the `UIViewController`.There are some buttons (`buttonOne`, `buttonTwo`, `buttonThree`) on the `UIView`. The `bottomViewController` have a `UIGestureRecognizer`.
Now, I have a touch event on the `upperView`; the touch point is outside of the buttons. The `upperView` will pass the event to its superview (`bottomViewController`).

How can I prevent `upperView` from passing the event - to which it can't respond - to its superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

int the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

return YES if you should receive touch NO if not, based on what ever logic you want to apply. You have the UITouch and UIGestureRecognizer which both contain lots of useful information.

Remember to set delegate of UIGestureRecognizer to self.

Comment: Thanks for your help!I will have a try!

Answer (score 0):

You could assign tags to views and then check for if condition and put up logic into it.